# Why can we not take gravity to act at the center of mass in this case?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, newtonian-gravity, symmetry, planets

I found this problem when I was trying to prove that the gravitational attraction on an object is the gravitational attraction on the center of mass of that object (I had doubts on it). And in doing so I ran into this problem which shows that the effect on the center of mass isn't equal to the effect on the whole thing

[image]

So why don't the two values equal...If the image I posted isn't clear heres everything non mathematical that was on the image. 'A' means the area of the circular face of the cylinder.' L' is the distance from the center of the circular face of the cylinder to the surface of Object A. Also the surface plane of the circular face of the cylinder is parallel to any tangential surface of Object A

Answer (score 2):

I didn't look over your work (check-my-work questions are off topic), but the conceptual error is still obvious. The gravitational field isn't uniform, so the force acts on the center of *gravity*, not the center of mass. For uniform fields these are the same thing, but in general they are not.

Comment: thanx for the answer but I don't think I know what you mean... the center of gravity is the same as the center of mass ... plus the reason I integrated it with respect to dr is because theres no uniform gravity

Comment: @alienare4422 No, the center of gravity is *not* the same thing as the center of mass. The center of gravity depends on the field as well as the object's orientation in that field. The center of mass just depends on the volume density of the object and is independent of the field.